# Adding extra space above graph with facet_wrap

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

I’m trying to use facet_wrap in r with 4 plots that have different x-axis. I used scales = “free” which was helpful, but most of the plots touch the top of the graph. I would like there to be space above the tallest bar of the graph, so it doesn’t look like it’s going off above the limit of the graph. I hope that makes sense - this is my first time posting a question here. I have provided the code that I have and a screenshot of one of the graphs. I haven't been able to find any sort of fix without using cow plot which is a bit more advanced than I would like.

**Code**:

```
wrap_plot <- df  %>% ggplot(aes(x=Race, y = Rate, fill = Sex))+
  geom_col(position = "dodge")+
  labs(x = "Race/Ethnicity",
       y = "Rate per 100,000 population")+
  theme_classic()+
  facet_wrap(~Disease, scales = "free")+
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0))
```

[image: Picture of graph]

Comment: Using `expand = c(0, 0)` you removed the default expansion of the scale at the bottom and the top. To keep the default expansion at the top try `scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0, .05, 0))` or the more verbose  `scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = c(0, .05)))`.

Comment: Please provide a sample of your data `df` using `dput(df)`

Comment: Removing expand = c(0, 0), as suggested, worked!!! Thank you so much for your help!